Unable to properly install Python 3.7.0 on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VBox machine
I am preparing a VirtualBox machine (Ubuntu 22.04) to work on a project with a friend and it needs to use Python 3.7.0. In order to install this python version, I am using the following command:
pyenv install 3.7.0 

However, I get the following error message which I don't get when installing python 3.7.0 locally on my host Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine:
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.7. The minimum supported Python version is 3.8. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.7/get-pip.py. 

When I navigate the URL provided, it downloads a .py file. Which after checking it out, I executed and the pip updated. However, it looks like that it does not solve the main issue of not being able to download and set up python 3.7.0 on the Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine.
Am I missing something?
If I do pyenv version --list I can clearly see that 3.7.0 exists. Why it does not allow me to install it?
I would glady appreciate some hints on how to achieve this purpose.

The problem does not say that Python 3.7 could not be installed, but that you require at least Python in version 3.8. to run this script.
Why don't you install the latest of 3.12.6?
Have you tried to to
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade


Thank you for your response. I was required to strictly work with 3.7.0. On the VBox machine I have installed 3.8.0 with pyenv and worked perfectly as expected, but when I do 'pyenv install 3.7.0' it shows the error message above. Even though I already have 3.8.0 installed.

Thanks for the update, my current pyenv version is 2.4.13 for both the local and virtual machine, this should not be an issue for allowing the local machine to proceed as expected and virtualbox fail.
